# Can't start any version mongodb... what should I do?

Tags: mongodb

This is the following error I'm getting:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Wed 2022-10-05 13:58:32 CEST; 5s >
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 26562 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=du>
   Main PID: 26562 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
        CPU: 15ms
```

I've already downloaded mongodb 5, 4.4 and 4 and tried to starting them.
But in all cases I get the error from above, I'm guessing that it might be my CPU. My CPU doesn't support mongodb5 so I tried with the rest versions of it. But none of them works.. what should I do?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* your CPU doesn’t allow MongoDB? Are you using a 386SX/25? 

Comment: @matigo I used 'grep avx /proc/cpuinfo / grep avx2 /proc/cpuinfo' these commends to see if my cpu supports v5.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the following answer from stackoverflow:

1.Stop the mongod process by issuing the following command:-

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

2.Remove any MongoDB packages that you had previously installed:-

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

3.Remove MongoDB databases and log files:-

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

4.Then reinstall mangodb 4.4.8

5.Import the public key used by the package management system:-

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

6.The following instruction is for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):-

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

7.Update Apt

```
sudo apt-get update
```

8.Install mongodb

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=4.4.8 mongodb-org-server=4.4.8 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.8 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.8 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.8
```

9.Use mongod --version to check its succesfully installed

10.If u encounter any error while using mongod

```
sudo mkdir /data
cd /data
sudo mkdir db
sudo pkill -f mongod
```

11.Then use sudo mongod command.

by Abdul Wahhab

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742794/mongodb-failed-result-core-dump